# How to grant control from applescript over Finder?

Tags: macos, applescript

I have applications (in JAVA) that send files to Trash.

This is done by osascript; on one account this works, on another it fails.

Obviously the first account lacks permissions to control Finder, which seems to do the hard work. How do I grant this permission in System Preferences, as I do not see any difference between those accounts in the Privacy list.

;JOOP!

Answer (score 0):

it seems that the terminal command

tccutil reset All

is the only way. Of course this is followed by several requests from the system to grant all kinds of privileges, but at least it gives back control to you.
Greetings. ;JOOP!